# How to install self-signed certificate to Windows Phone 7 Emulator

Tags: windows-phone-7, ssl, https

I read through many post on Stackoverflow about this problem, but I can't seem to find any solution

I have a web server running on IIS 7.5 and use self signed certificate for it, so that https service can be called by WP7.

I have a client (WP7) and I want to install that certificate to my emulator to test. I tried export the certificate to .cer, .p7b, and have that file included in the web server so that my WP7 emulator can access it. The emulator shows a message box indicating that "the certificate has been installed successfully", I even try to change regional setting so that the emulator can "reset", however WP7 still can't access https service on web server.

Can we install self signed certificate on WP7 emulator, or we can just install on real device ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are specific requirements in effect for SSL certificates that can be used with Windows Phone, outlined [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg521150%28v=VS.92%29.aspx). Self-signed certificates won't play nice with secure services.

> The Root Certificate Authority (CA) of the certificate must be one of
>   the CAs listed

([source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff941099%28v=VS.92%29.aspx))

Answer (score 0):

The only way to install a self signed certificate on Windows Phone is to point the browser to a cert file URL on a remote server. So it seems that you are doing it right.

I do this for my production app and it works fine on the emulator and on devices. Every time you close the emulator you will lose the cert and have to do an install when you open it again.

If it is still not working, then it must be the cert to blame.

Comment: also not work for me.BTW,if there is a way to see the current CA list after i install a new certificate