# HttpStatusCode.NotFoundfrom server with ssl

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

in my Windows Phone application that communicates with server with ssl appear some problem. For each request client recieve from server HttpStatusCode.NotFound. How can I fix this issue?

On server side we are using preinstalled Thawte Primary Root CA certificate

Comment: Are you sure the handset has data/wifi connectivity? A 404 status code is usually returned when there is no connectivity on the phone/emulator. Also, does the uri exists when you point it to a browser directly?

Comment: I try this on emulator and my computer has wifi connection and internet

Comment: web url exist, this issue appear after change ssl sertificate on server side

Comment: AFAIK 404 Not Found has nothing to do with SSL certificate, I guess you are serving the wrong www root directory in your IIS website config.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue with Windows Phone operating system. When the SSL connection doesn't meet OS expectations it [will return you 404 status code](http://www.markermetro.com/2013/06/technical/dealing-with-self-signed-ssl-certificates-on-windows-phone/).

- Make sure that the date on the phone and on the emulator is correct.
- Make sure that certificate [is installed on your phone or emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11473589/how-to-install-self-signed-certificate-to-windows-phone-7-emulator?rq=1).